# How to select records from last 24 hours using SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime

I am looking for a `where` clause that can be used to retrieve records for the last 24 hours?

Comment: Do you have a timestamp field on these records?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE table_name.the_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: If the records are stored as `DATETIME`, this will select all records from the previous date, disregarding the time part. Been run at `23:59:59`, the query will return all records for the last `48` hours, not `24`.

Comment: If you want to select the last 24 hours from a datetime field, substitute 'curate()' with 'now()'. This also includes the time.

Answer (score 721):

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   record_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

In `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   record_date >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

In `Oracle`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   record_date >= SYSDATE - 1
```

In `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   record_date >= NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
```

In `Redshift`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   record_date >= GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
```

In `SQLite`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   record_date >= datetime('now','-1 day')
```

In `MS Access`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   record_date >= (Now - 1)
```

Comment: I try the query for mysql but if its 2AM, for example, i get the records from 00 - 02 AM. Two hours only instead of 24. Any ideas?

Comment: I very  much like the solution provided here, just what I noted in MySQL is the performance of _Guillaume Flandre_ solution was faster.

Comment: In Amazon Redshift, I get `function getdate() does not exist`. Replaced it with `current_date` and it worked fine.

Comment: @Manos In MySQL, it looks like `CURDATE()` doesn't return a date with a time portion, so it goes to `00`. I fixed it by using `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()`.

Answer (score 23):

MySQL :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE table_name.the_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

The INTERVAL can be in YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND

For example, In the last 10 minutes

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE table_name.the_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Comment: This is the answer that best answers the specific question: How to return the PRECEDING 24 HOURS (from present moment), as opposed to the previous 24 (which suggests all results for previous day). This answered my requirements, this gets my upvote.
EDIT: Its worth mentioning the table_name.the_date column should be a timestamp.

Answer (score 8):

Which SQL was not specified, SQL 2005 / 2008

```
SELECT yourfields from yourTable WHERE yourfieldWithDate > dateadd(dd,-1,getdate())
```

If you are on the 2008 increased accuracy date types, then use the new sysdatetime() function instead, equally if using UTC times internally swap to the UTC calls.

Answer (score 7):

in postgres, assuming your field type is a timestamp:

> select * from table where date_field > (now() - interval '24 hour');

Answer (score 4):

If the timestamp considered is a UNIX timestamp
You need to first convert UNIX timestamp (e.g 1462567865) to mysql timestamp or data

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(order_ts) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: That's assuming the engine being used is MySQL as FROM_UNIXTIME() is a MySQL function.

For SQL Server use:

```SELECT DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', DateField)```

If you need millisecond accuracy in SQL Server 2016 and later use: 

```SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(millisecond, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', DateField)```

Comment: This runs a function on each row, and will not benefit from index. Ok for smaller amounts of data or one time operations, not so ok for repeated use on large datasets.

Answer (score 3):

```
select ...
from ...
where YourDateColumn >= getdate()-1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE datecolumn >= dateadd(hour,-24,getdate())
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello i now it past a lot of time from the original post but i got a similar problem and i want to share.

I got a datetime field with this format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss, and i want to access a whole day, so here is my solution.

The function DATE(), in MySQL: Extract the date part of a date or datetime expression.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE DATE(`your_datatime_field`)='2017-10-09'
```

with this i get all the row register in this day.

I hope its help anyone.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me on mySQL. For some reason when I tried SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate > DATE_SUB('2018-06-13 00:00:00', INTERVAL 24 HOUR); I was still getting records from 2018-06-14.

Comment: This runs a function on each row, and will not benefit from index. Ok for smaller amounts of data or one time operations, not so ok for repeated use on large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server (For last 24 hours):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   order_date > DateAdd(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) and order_date<=GETDATE()
```

Comment: why would you need to add "and order_date <=GETDATE()" when you are already looking for last 24 hours form the moment of exection of that query? It really makes no sense to have that part in the where clause when you have "GETDATE" already mentioned in the first one. You better make it "order_date >= DateAdd(DAY, -1, GETDATE())" thats it!

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle (For last 24 hours):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    my_table
WHERE   date_column >= SYSDATE - 24/24
```

In case, for any reason, you have rows with future dates, you can use *between*, like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    my_table
WHERE   date_column BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 24/24) AND SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone might need this as it is my case. If you want to select a record after 24 hours, you can change the `>=` to `<=`

For example: In MySQL will be:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   record_date <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```