# Compare dates in Rails with associated model without using .select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry if this has been posted elsewhere, not sure what to search for.

I have this query that is currently using `.select`, but there must be a better way to get the same result without using the dreaded `.select`? The mission is: find all shift cancellations that were created within 6 hours of when the shift was supposed to start:

```
ShiftCancellation.select{|c| c.created_at > c.shift.date_time - 6.hours}
```

`ShiftCancellation belongs_to :shift` and vice versa.

I'm on Postgres, so SQL-exclusive queries won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can join to the other table to allow all fields to be queried, but I'm not sure what the best way to get the date - 6hours is. I think [DATE_SUB](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp) may be what you need:

```
ShiftCancellation.joins(:shift).where("shift_cancellations.created_at > DATE_SUB(shifts.date_time, INTERVAL 6 HOUR)"}
```

Bunch of examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1888569/385532

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to mention I'm on Postgres, so DATE_SUB won't work.

Comment: @mantralux check the examples in the link, there's a postgres alternative

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
ShiftCancellation.joins(:shift).where("shift_cancellations.created_at > (shifts.date_time - interval '6 hours')")
```