# Total of all values in a day (24h)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to add all values in a database from the last 24 hours. Each value has its TimeStamp in the database.

I tried to do that with a for-loop, which adds 86400 secs (24h) every time, picks all values from one day and after that it adds all values.

Heres my code:

```
> `$datestart = 153839251200; //start date

for($uts = $uts; $uts > $datestart; $datestart + 86400){ 

if (($uts <= ($datestart + 86400)) && ($uts > $datestart)){

$uts = $datestart + 86400;

$valueFinal = $valueFinal + $value;   

 }
}

if($Zeitalt != $uts){

  $Zeitalt=date('l, F j y H:i:s',$uts);
  $uts *= 1000; // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time 
  $data[] = array((float)$uts,(float) $valueFinal);


 }`
```

I hope this explanation is enough, I'm not English speaking as much, otherwise just ask for more information.

Regards DR.Alfred

Comment: What is the question ? You have given us PHP code; with no details about your table structure and some relevant sample data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1888593/522479 could be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this as SQL so I'm assuming an answer in SQL is what you're looking for.

Firstly, I'm not sure why you're going to the effort of using a loop to get the total when SQL has the SUM function.

I'll give you this in T-SQL as I'm not familiar with MySQL but it shouldn't be too difficult to change it to MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(YourValue) 
FROM 
    YourTable 
WHERE 
    YourTimeStamp > getdate() - 1
```

I think the MySQL equivalent of GETDATE() is NOW().

Comment: I tried it like this:                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                               
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM($total) * FROM `Messwerte` WHERE $uts >= NOW() - INTERNAL 1 DAY"); //$uts: TimeStamp

Comment: So what happened when you ran this?  I'm not an expert on MySQL but I wouldn't think you would need the * in the select.  Also, you should be using INTERVAL, not INTERNAL.